# How would a programcode/algorithm look like with a running time of O(n^2 log n)

Tags: big-o

I have to wirte a Programm with the running time mentioned above i know how i would make n log n that would be binary search or n^2 which would just be 2 for loops. But i don't get to the point to make a combination of it

Comment: Have you tried something on your own?

Comment: Could it be any algorithm? Iterative algorithm with nested loops are acceptable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no single correct way to do this. Here are a few options:

1. Design an algorithm that inserts n<sup>2</sup> elements into a balanced BST. This does O(log n) work n<sup>2</sup> times. (This uses the fact that log n<sup>2</sup> = 2 log n = O(log n).)
2. Sort n<sup>2</sup> elements with heapsort or mergesort. More generally, run any O(n log n)-time algorithm on an input of size n<sup>2</sup>.
3. Write a recursive algorithm whose runtime is given by the recurrence T(n) ≤ 4T(n / 2) + n<sup>2</sup>. This does n<sup>2</sup> work per level and has O(log n) levels, and by the Master Theorem solves to O(n<sup>2</sup> log n).

Hopefully this gets you going in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Posted elsewhere as a question: What is the maximum running time of sorting n strings, each having a length of n characters? (Hint: String comparison is not a trivial operation).